# creativenativequery with ms sql, two line function call

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, mssql-jdbc

Okay so I was looking at someone's code and the guy is working on spring boot 2.1.1
He had changed his entire createStoredProcedureQuery, that calls a stored procedure in ms sql DB, into a 2 line createnative query. I wanna know how that was done.

I have tried searching on the net but couldn't find anything like that. When using createNativeQuery you send in the actual sql procedure, the actual sql code like for ex-

```
createNativeQuery("exec proc1",proc1mapping)
```

for ms sql server procedure call. But this guys is using -

```
Entitymanager em

 Queryquery=em.createNativeQuery("proc1:param1,:param2","proc1mapping");
    //for setting param1
    query.setParameter("param1","Somevalue");
```

How was this done. Please someone tell me, its driving me crazy.
Thanks :)

P.S. Sorry for any wrong formatting and bad question, my first post here

Comment: *Sorry for any wrong formatting and bad question, my first post here* Edit post and fix formatting.

Comment: And whats the problem here? It seems it is valid syntax for ms. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- Is used here

Comment: @Antoniossss hey thanks for the quick reply, okay so I'm new to all this spring boot jpa. Okay so just to be clear both of the ms sql calls are valid syntax?

Comment: Its hardly JPA related. I don't know about validity of syntax. I never used that RDBMS.